# Getting color histogram of a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

What is the best way to get the color histogram of a html page as rendered, when I have the html and css files locally?  I can think of a screen capture and then analyzing it using some graphic tool, but is there a more direct way to do this, for example, something like calculating it from the html and css information using JavaScript?

Comment: Are you talking about grabbing a color of screen? Google for ColorPic

Comment: Cool idea.  Did you find anything on this?

Comment: You could use http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ to render the page body into a canvas and then access the rendered pixel via the canvas image data. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/canvas-from-scratch-pixel-manipulation/

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about javascript, but you can use python with Qt and webkit as described in this [post](http://rolandtapken.de/blog/2008-12/create-screenshots-web-page-using-python-and-qtwebkit)

There is also a python [package](https://github.com/AdamN/python-webkit2png) inspired by the post

Hope that helps